# IMAP Outlook Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed

Tags: php, imap

I'm fetching some emails on Outlook with a PHP script, the code was working until last week.
Error message:

```
[0] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed.
[1] => Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed.
[2] => Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Code:

```
    imap_open('{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $username, $password);
    print_r(imap_errors());
```

The credentials works just fine, but it seems that I get a strange 2FA message once logged in, which I don't know where it comes from as that user doesn't have 2FA activated.

[image]

I tried changing password, but it doesn't work.
In the multi-factor authentication area on Office 365 admin it says that my 2FA is disabled. So I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: You cannot log into Office 365 with a password anymore:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online
You will need to use OAUTH and friends.  There are dozens of recent questions about this.

Comment: Thank you very much, strange I searched quite a lot and wasn't able to find any related issues, the only ones were super old.